# How to install migration in Rails engine from other engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have an engine, that has gem dependency. This gem has rake task to install migrations:

```
rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations
```

What is the proper way to install migration? When I run this command from host app or my engine I getting

> Don't know how to build task

Comment: I don't get why this question is downvoted and has a close vote as "Unclear what you are asking"  as its a rather straight forward question about mounting an engine in another engine.

Comment: The question could be improved by including the relevant code (gemspec, the engine.rb file).

Answer (score 0):

Add the gem dependency to you gemspec:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # ...
  s.add_dependency 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 6.0'
  # ...
end
```

Then require the gem in your engine:

```
# lib/my_engine/engine.rb
require 'acts-as-taggable-on'

module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Chatty
  end
end
```

`ActsAsTaggableOn` should be loaded through the main file which requires the engine as well unlike some gems where you require `gemname/engine` - and the file naming is not `snake_case` like most gems.

Then run `bundle install` and `rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations` in the folder of the dummy application (or the host).

```
max@MaxBook ~/p/c/t/dummy> rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations
Copied migration 20181030123059_acts_as_taggable_on_migration.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb from acts_as_taggable_on_engine
Copied migration 20181030123060_add_missing_unique_indices.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb from acts_as_taggable_on_engine
Copied migration 20181030123061_add_taggings_counter_cache_to_tags.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb from acts_as_taggable_on_engine
Copied migration 20181030123062_add_missing_taggable_index.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb from acts_as_taggable_on_engine
Copied migration 20181030123063_change_collation_for_tag_names.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb from acts_as_taggable_on_engine
Copied migration 20181030123064_add_missing_indexes_on_taggings.acts_as_taggable_on_engine.rb from acts_as_taggable_on_engine
```

I don't know why but invoking the command through bundler (`bundle exec ...`) does not work. This may give problems with RVM if you are using shims.

You can also create a generator for your engine that invokes the task:

```
# lib/generators/my_engine/install/install_generator.rb
module MyEngine
  class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    source_root File.expand_path('templates', __dir__)

    desc "Installs MyEngine"

    def copy_initializer
      # template 'my_engine.rb', 'config/initializers/my_engine.rb'
      rake "acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations"
    end
  end
end
```

Which you can then run with `rails g my_engine:install`.